# Javascript add class

Tags: javascript, web

I have this line in javascript `document.getElementById("load").classList.add("active");` but not working. Where is problem and what I must change?

In html I have

```
<div class="loading" id="load"></div>
```

And I need with javascript add class `active` to this div.

Comment: Tested and working.... can't find a problem here

Comment: Tested and works fine. Is your script being called in an event or at the start of the page? In the second case, maybe you're executing it before the DOM is fully loaded.

Comment: Check console for any error

Answer (score 4):

Your code looks fine, just make sure your JS code executed after building the DOM, the below code will ensure that:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.getElementById("load").classList.add("active");
});
```